# Arduino code for custom robot arm

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you give me an example of arduino code for moveit. I can’t find any examples. Which information should node publish to controller? Servomotor   pose or so?. Maybe there are some tutorials?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279501/arduino-code-for-custom-robot-arm/) by [Evgenia](https://answers.ros.org/users/27776/evgenia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-01-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-10**:
You want someone to write code for you? If that's what you're looking for that's not how it works. We'll *hekp* you with problems but we won't do your work for you. If I'm mistaken, please let me know and update your question with more detail.

**Comment by [Evgenia](https://answers.ros.org/users/27776/evgenia/) on 2018-01-10**:
Thank you for your comment! I’ve updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
#include "Arduino.h"
#else
#include <WProgram.h>
#endif

```
 #include <Servo.h> 
 #include <ros.h>
 #include <std_msgs/UInt16.h>

 ros::NodeHandle  nh;

 Servo servo1;
 Servo servo2;
 Servo servo3;
 Servo servo4;
 Servo servo5;
 Servo servo6;


  void servo_cb1( const std_msgs::UInt16& cmd_msg){
  servo1.write(cmd_msg.data); //set servo angle, should be from 0-180  

  }

  void servo_cb2( const std_msgs::UInt16& cmd_msg){
   servo2.write(cmd_msg.data); //set servo angle, should be from 0-180  

   }

   void servo_cb3( const std_msgs::UInt16& cmd_msg){
   servo3.write(cmd_msg.data); //set servo angle, should be from 0-180  

   }

   void servo_cb4( const std_msgs::UInt16& cmd_msg){
   servo4.write(cmd_msg.data); //set servo angle, should be from 0-180  

   }
  void servo_cb5( const std_msgs::UInt16& cmd_msg){
  servo5.write(cmd_msg.data); //set servo angle, should be from 0-180  

  }

  void servo_cb6( const std_msgs::UInt16& cmd_msg){
  servo6.write(cmd_msg.data); //set servo angle, should be from 0-180  

  }


   ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::UInt16> sub1("servo1", servo_cb1);
   ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::UInt16> sub2("servo2", servo_cb2);
   ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::UInt16> sub3("servo3", servo_cb3);
   ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::UInt16> sub4("servo4", servo_cb4);
   ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::UInt16> sub5("servo5", servo_cb5);
   ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::UInt16> sub6("servo6", servo_cb6);

   void setup(){
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(8, OUTPUT);

    nh.initNode();
    nh.subscribe(sub1);
    nh.subscribe(sub2);
    nh.subscribe(sub3);
    nh.subscribe(sub4);
    nh.subscribe(sub5);
    nh.subscribe(sub6);

    servo1.attach(13); //attach it to pin 13
    servo2.attach(12);
    servo3.attach(11); //attach it to pin 11
    servo4.attach(10);
    servo1.attach(9); //attach it to pin 9
    servo2.attach(8);

    }

    void loop(){
    nh.spinOnce();
    delay(1);
     }
```

---

Originally posted by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) with karma: 142 on 2018-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Evgenia](https://answers.ros.org/users/27776/evgenia/) on 2018-01-16**:
Thank you! It is very useful!

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-01-17**:
Move it , i am also trying to figure out , once i figure it our i will share .

For move it , you need to first sort out the URDF model of the robotic arm .

I have a 16 channel PCA9685 servo module (it can be operated via I2C). I am trying to figure out how to control the module vai nodemcu.

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-01-17**:
https://github.com/ksatyaki/JacoROS

Try this , might work.

**Comment by [Evgenia](https://answers.ros.org/users/27776/evgenia/) on 2018-01-17**:
Thank you! I'll try!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finaly, I've got how do this. There is topic: /joint_states it gives radians of position of  each knee of manipulator. I've transformed this data to servo steps in ros node and then sent them to arduino using UInt8MultiArray! And it works! After all arduino subscriber looks like this:

```
void servo_cb( const std_msgs::UInt8MultiArray& cmd_msg){
    for(short i = 0; i<=4; i++)
        myservo[i].write(cmd_msg.data[i]);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Evgenia](https://answers.ros.org/users/27776/evgenia/) with karma: 21 on 2018-01-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-05-31**:
Hello @Evgenia, is there anyway you can show how you have put these values into an array? I am struggling to reproduce what you have described here...

**Comment by [Rakee003](https://answers.ros.org/users/86408/rakee003/) on 2021-10-12**:
have you sought the issue, i am also struggling for the same problem. Can you help me @matthewmarkey